# Taking inputs with commas from UI to python code at backend

Tags: python, api, input

I am currently working on a UI which takes inputs with numbers such as 500000. To the user, as the user inputs the number, we want to display it as 500,000. This input field is coded as a 'float' input field in the PY code at the backend. Now as a value of 500,000 versus 500000 is passed, the code is erroring out. Same problem with %s i.e. if somebody is inputting say 4 percent, as the user inputs 4, we are displaying 4% - this is also giving an error with the code. Any thoughts on potential remedies?

Answer (score 0):

I am not certain if I understood the question correctly, so let me rephrase:

You are dealing with different string-inputs such as:

```
'500000'
'500,000'
'4'
'4%'
```

And you have trouble converting them via `float()`, I assume due to ValueErrors.

If this is correct, I would suggest to remove the problematic characters, try to convert to float and use 0 if conversion still fails:

```
def convert_to_float(input):
    # remove problematic characters
    for character in [',', '%']:
        input = input.replace(character, "")
    try:
        return float(input)
    except ValueError:  # still unable to convert to float
        return 0  # or , if you want to see the error, remove the try/except and just use float(input)
```